# automatically delete columns from a csv file

Tags: php, shell

Here's my problem: I need to automatically delete specific columns from a csv file before parsing it using fgetcsv in php. If I don't delete those columns (which i really don't need), i get an out of memory error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if commandline is an option but if so the `cut` command will save your day. If you are running low on memory you might want to process your csv with `cut` before actually loading it with php.

**my.csv**

```
a;b;c;d;
0;1;2;3;
0;1;2;3;
0;1;2;3;
0;1;2;3;
0;1;2;3;
0;1;2;3;
0;1;2;3;
0;1;2;3;
0;1;2;3;
```

**Command: removes the third column**

```
cut -d ";" -f1-2,4- my.csv
```

**Output**

```
a;b;d;
0;1;3;
0;1;3;
0;1;3;
0;1;3;
0;1;3;
0;1;3;
0;1;3;
0;1;3;
0;1;3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple php script you could unset the field to remove it from the output file.

This example removes the 2nd field from the `$inFile` and saves the result in the `$outFile`

```
<?php
$read = fopen($inFile, 'r');
$write = fopen($outFile, 'w');
if ($write && $read) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($read)) !== FALSE) {
        unset($data[1]);
        fputcsv($write, $data);
    }
}
fclose($write);
fclose($read);
```

If you are having memory issues though, a better alternative may be to write a script to move the data into a database, then you can query for just the data and fields that you need.